# Lucene create similarity matrix - compare documents

Tags: java, lucene, similarity, information-retrieval

I have n users (at the moment only 1000 it should be more than 100'000 in the future so it shouldn't be too inefficient).

The users are visualized as m (usually 1-10) documents. In my first attempt I concat the documents in one String. The String contains all different letters, numbers and special character ("/", "\r\n", "&", "+", ...) everything can be possible.

In the end I want to have a nxn matrix with a similarity score that compare each document to each other. (the diagonal should be the highest score because it's most similar to himself)

Example:

```
user/user| userA | userB | userC |
userA    | 1.00  | 0.94  | 0.33  |
userB    | 0.92  | 1.00  | 0.12  |
userC    | 0.35  | 0.22  | 1.00  |
```

That's what I want to achieve. I'm using Lucene but I think I can switch to another framework too when Lucene doesn't provide it.

I have done this:

```
public class Similarity {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        UserFactory userFactory = UserFactory.getInstance();
        UserBase base = userFactory.getUserFromCsv("user.csv");
        Similarity sim = new Similarity();
        sim.indexing(base);
    }

    private StandardAnalyzer analyzer = null;
    private Directory index = null;
    private IndexWriterConfig config = null;
    private IndexWriter w = null;

    public Similarity() throws IOException {
        analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
        index = new RAMDirectory();
        config = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer);
        w = new IndexWriter(index, config);
    }

    public void query(User user){
        // How??
    }


    public void indexing(UserBase base) throws IOException {
        for(User user : base.getUsers()){
                addDoc(w, user.getText(), user.getId());                
            }
        }
        w.close();
    }

    private void addDoc(IndexWriter w, String text, String id) throws IOException {
        Document doc = new Document();
        doc.add(new TextField("text", text, Field.Store.YES));
        doc.add(new StringField("id", id, Field.Store.YES));   
        w.addDocument(doc);
    }
}
```

The User class is really simple and only have 2 fields text and id. I want to compare the text for each user: `user.getText()`

My first attempt was to try a normal Query parser:

```
public void query(User user){
    IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(index);
    IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
    Query q = new QueryParser("text",analyzer).parse(user.getText());
    TopDocs docs = searcher.search(q,10000);
    for(ScoreDoc hit : docs.scoreDocs){
        Document d = searcher.doc(hit.doc);
        System.out.println(d.getId() + " " + hit.score);
    }
}
```

The problem in this attempt was the following:

1. I have to replace all special character before I could let it run (replace "/" - probably more I only tested it with one document and I never know which character could be a problem in the future)
2. The most similar user is not the user I used as a query - more worse he doesn't even appear in the list...
3. But when I use only a subset (first 20 character) he find the user I used as a query - strange? probably a flaw in my thinking...

But yeah I don't think that's the best approach to solve this problem...

I also tried it with MoreLikeThis (already deleted the code sorry... but it didn't work I couldn't even get a result it was always empty even if I compare everything with everyone).

I'm a beginner with Lucene so yeah could be a few flaws in my thinking.

Comment: Just curious, what goes in "text" of a user? is it just user name? 

Ideally if you split your user data to multiple fields (e.g. name, address, phone etc) and run BooleanQuery you should be able to get better results (you can also assign weight per field during your query).

StandardAnalyzer offers generic tokenizer which helps on standard text data, if you have specific need you can either add your additional pre-processing step for removing/replacing specific characters or create your own custom analyzer/tokenizer/filter to meet your exact requirements.

Comment: PDF's that are from different formats. So I don't have any clue. For some PDF's I have to use OCR too so I can't separate by fields...